# How to get tab page's index by its name in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a dynamically created tab page's index by its name with no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a poorly designed question, take a look at [ask] for a better way to get your question viewed and answered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how I asked was enough to get a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to search the tabpages' properties and return the index:

```
Dim i As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, TabControl1.TabPages.Count).Where(Function(x) TabControl1.TabPages(x).Name.Equals("TabPage1")).FirstOrDefault
```